# Why does Pygame NEED an event handler to function?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

It makes no sense to me why it's absolutely necessary to make a call to an event handler in order for the screen to be coloured. 
With the event handler called, the screen is shown green.

Take out the call to the event handler and the screen remains uncoloured - it doesn't even hang in a red state and the loop can still be seen to run continuously. So the addition of an event handler makes all the difference, but WHY?!

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def event_handler():      
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            quit()  

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))

screen.fill((255,0,0)) # red screen
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    screen.fill((0,250,0)) # green screen
    pygame.display.update()
    print("running")
    event_handler()
    clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate.
```

Comment: It actually colors the screen for me even without the `event_handler` function, but the window becomes unresponsive after a while.

Comment: I think the duplicate question and associated answer regarding the event buffer being constantly used is appropriate here, so I have closed this question.
However, I think it's interesting that you have a coloured screen - Which colour, red or green? Did it become unresponsive only when it reached the loop?

Comment: It's green. "Did it become unresponsive only when it reached the loop? " Yes, that's the normal behavior if you don't handle the events each frame.